# react native image picker give an errror: Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of null

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

i have an issue in react native image picker when the function launchImageLibrary called then it gave an error [TypeError: Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of null]

```
const ImagePicker = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await launchImageLibrary({
                mediaType: 'photo',
                includeBase64: false,
                maxHeight: 200,
                maxWidth: 200,
            });
            console.log(result)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

}
```

i want to pick the image from device in react native